# Why am I getting an IndexError on this program?

Tags: python

I am trying to make this code that will subtract the second line item from the first line item. Everytime I run this program, I get `IndexError: list index out of range`. I am calling range 0 and 1 from the text document but it won't do the calculation.

```
test = open("test.txt", "r")
num1 = int(test.readlines()[0])
num2 = int(test.readlines()[1])
print(num1 - num2)
```

Here's the values in the test file. I would expect it to output 250.

```
500
250
```

I expect the code to do the calculation to output the calculation result.

Comment: As a side note, you *could* move the file pointer back to the start of the buffer by calling `test.buffer.seek(0)` between your `num1 = ` and `num2 = `. But seriously, don't do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first call to `readlines` gives you all the lines in the file and leaves the file pointer at the end of the file. The second call, then, has nothing left to read, and returns an empty list.

Either read the entire file once, and use that list to define `num1` and `num2`:

```
with open("test.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

num1 = int(lines[0])
num2 = int(lines[1])
```

or read one line at a time with the `readline` (no "s") method.

```
with open("test.txt") as f:
    num1 = int(f.readline())
    num2 = int(f.readline())
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling `readlines` once returns all lines of the file in a list. Calling it again returns an empty list. Because the lines are already read in the first call. The snippet below will make it clear:

```
test = open("data.txt", "r")
print(test.readlines())
print(test.readlines())
```

Output:

```
['500\n', '250\n']
[]
```

In your script, the call to `readlines` in line 3 gets `[]`. This empty list does not have anything at index 1, hence the Index Error.

You can refactor like this to make it work:

```
test = open("data.txt", "r")
lines = test.readlines()
num1 = int(lines[0])
num2 = int(lines[1])
print(num1 - num2)
```

Even better if you use `with` to take care of closing the file once you're done.

```
with open("data.txt", "r") as test:
    lines = test.readlines()
    num1 = int(lines[0])
    num2 = int(lines[1])
    print(num1 - num2)
```